# Checking jquery `success` method parameter issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I want to `console.log` the values of jquery `ajax` success method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/CalculateTime.asmx/GetServerTime',
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (e) {},
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("success: " + data);
    }
});
```

but it only display `[object object]` in the browser console and does not show what actually data is returned by server..

```
            [WebMethod]
public DateTime GetServerTime()
{
       return DateTime.Now;
}
```

I tried

```
         success: function(e) {


        console.log("success: "+e );
    }
```

but no use.. what is wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
console.log('success');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: If you put them together, it's going write it as a string, not an object.

Comment: programming is such a joy.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
console.log("success: "+ JSON.stringify(data) );
```

You will get a JSON string printed.

Or put a debugger there, to inspect the data object... It's better.

`[Object object]` is what you get by default when you try to print an object. Google it...  [Object.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Thanks but normally I output the success value like the above and it works perfectly fine..

Comment: but now I am confused why it is not outputing the object by saying console.log(data);